# How to add a list of specific worksheets to the list in ComboBox VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I found a way to add all of the worksheets in the workbook into the list of the ComboBox on the UserForm, which is done with use of the following code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        cmbSheet.AddItem ws.Name
    Next ws
End Sub
```

My problem is that I only need to add some specific worksheets and not all of them. For example my user will select specific sheet and by clicking "Continue" button should end up on the selected worksheet to continue his/her task. My workbook holds several worksheets, some of which are used to output data (Reports) and some worksheets contain so called templates, which I want my user (only those) to be able to select from the ComboBox I have talked above.

Can you guys help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you could use a naming convention for the worksheets?

if the reports you want the user to select all have the word *temmplate* in their name you could do something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        if instr(lcase(ws.name),"template")<>0 then
            cmbSheet.AddItem ws.Name
        end if
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, one question, how to get to the worksheet that is selected in the ComboBox by clicking the button, what code should I place in the following Private Sub ContinueButton_Click()
    
End Sub

Comment: @AlexB: you could look at the combobox `SelectedItem` property. If you need further help, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks Philip, I will give it a try, will ask a new question if I need more help.

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        if ws.Name like "*Template" then cmbSheet.AddItem ws.Name
    Next ws
End Sub
```